# Constructor of attribute decorating the main method does not get called in release builds

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Does anyone know why the constructor of an attribute decorating the main method is called in debug builds, but not in release builds?
How can I ensure that the constructor is called in release builds as well? Without calling it manually of course.

Any insight on this subject would be very much appreciated.

Comment: And how exactly have you come to this conclusion? And please dont tell me you tried to debug it when optimization is on....

Comment: Without code , it's impossible to think something, please post something to eat :)

Comment: @leppie - there's nothing wrong with his conclusion

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't add any code example. I thought my short explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this (in both debug and release), **when executed via the IDE** with the "Debug" => "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option enabled, via the below. At the command-line it will print "hello", where-as via the IDE it will print "world". It looks like the IDE is doing some different reflection on the attributes.

This is ***not*** expected behaviour, and you should not rely on this behaviour. If you want some particular code to execute: invoke the desired code explicitly. To get predictable behaviour, disable the Debug" => "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.

```
using System;
public class MyTestAttribute : Attribute {
    public MyTestAttribute() {
        Program.text = "world";
    }
}
class Program {
    public static string text = "hello";
    [MyTest]
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that this not expected behaviour, since the STAThread attribute decorates the main method as well. Thanks for your confirmation. Rethinking design... ;)

Comment: @NullAndVoid - attributes are generally *markers* rather than expected to take an active roll. I *expect* it is actually `STAThread` that it is looking for, but where-as the core CLR might check with `Attribute.IsDefined`, maybe the VS host process is calling `GetAttributes` (which forces materialization) and *then* filtering to see if `[STAThread]` was in there.